# shortcut icon not showing in IE and Chrome

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to show a shortcut icon in my Oracle Apex application. I'm using a workspace image so I uploaded the image in the Apex workspace and changed the shortcut icon line in the page template header :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#NED_NGdW.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

The image shows correctly in Firefox.

Page source shows:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file?p_security_group_id=6528703319516854&p_fname=NED_NGdW.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

However in IE9 and Chrome I still see the old standard icon. Clearing browser cache does not solve this.

Is there an issue using #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# and shortcut icons?

Using Apex 4.02

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer:
The page template contains to references to an icon:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#my_image.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#my_image.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Changed both of them.

Comment: Changed to what?